# Curve from selected vertices/edges using low level api

Tags: python, scripting, bezier-curves

I want to convert selected vertices/edges into curves. I can convert them using bpy.ops functions. But is there any alternative using lower level api preferable using bmesh.
I can get all spline points to proper position but not in proper order so I get this mesh(middle) not the expected curve(left).
[image]

Here is the code.

```py
import bpy
import bmesh

def create_curve(coords_list):
    # make a new curve
    crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
    crv.dimensions = '3D'

    # make a new spline in that curve
    spline = crv.splines.new(type='POLY')

    # a spline point for each point
    spline.points.add(len(coords_list)-1) # theres already one point by default
    
    # assign the point coordinates to the spline points
    for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
        x,y,z = new_co
        p.co = (x,y,z,1)
    
    # make a new object with the curve
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new('object_name', crv)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
    
def main(context):
    
    obj = context.active_object
    if obj.mode == 'EDIT':
        # this works only in edit mode,
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
        selected_verts = list(filter(lambda v: v.select, bm.verts))
        pos = list(map(lambda v: v.co,selected_verts))
        
        create_curve(pos)

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27785745/10358314) stack overflow thread. Solution in that thread works for closed loop. I tried to modify it to work for non-closed loop/selected edges but no success. Modified script works in some cases in other gives weird results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Walk the edges.**

To give them some order walk the edges.  It may take more than one spline to make the curve, since we cannot branch.  For example the default cube when "de-faced" and converted to curve has 4 splines.

Here is test script to walk the selected edges. It does not make the curve, rather creates an ordered list of the edges to use in each spline.

- Get all selected edges.
- Pop an edge, get its two end verts. Tag the edge.
- Grow spline from each end on a non tagged and selected edge, prepend at one end, append at other.
- Add spline to splines.
- Repeat until no more edges to process.

Script

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from collections import defaultdict

from bpy import context
tag = defaultdict(bool)

ob = context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
# selected edges
edges = list(filter(lambda e: e.select, bm.edges))
# all edges
#edges = bm.edges[:]

splines = []
def tag_remove(edge):
    tag[edge] = True
    edges.remove(edge)

def grow(end, spline, idx):
     while True:
        nextedge = next(
            (e for e in end.link_edges if not tag[e] and  e.select), 
            None
            )
        if not nextedge:
            return
        tag_remove(nextedge)
        spline.insert(idx, nextedge.index)
        end = nextedge.other_vert(end)   
    
while edges:

    edge = edges.pop()
    spline = [edge.index]
    tag[edge] = True
    a, b = edge.verts
    grow(a, spline, 0)
    grow(b, spline, len(edges))
    splines.append(spline)
    
print(splines)
```

Result for default cube. Notice 4 splines as with convert.

```
[[5, 1, 0, 3, 6, 11, 7], [4, 10], [2, 9], [8]]
```

Result for default circle.  Since edge 30 shares a vert with edge 31 could make this cyclic.

```
[[30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 31]]
```

To reverse order, could try swapping which end to append / prepend...